# Formula for grass green and greener

Tags: data-analysis, image-processing

Within the science project we are watering grass with water using different level and technique of treatment and cleaning. We measure traces of biological and chemical materials within the soil as well as within the plants. And we have also series of pictures of the grass.

I'm looking for some ideas how to come up with measure how to convert the image into some sort of *greenness index*, preferably as a single number or short vector of few numbers. The plan is to correlate it later to point in time and to level of chemical elements in the plants.

Here are some images - two different water treatments, monthly images from June to October:

| Sample | June | July | August | September | October |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Sample 1 | [image: Sample 1 - June] | [image] | [image] | [image] | [image] |
| Sample 2 | [image: Sample 1 - June] | [image] | [image] | [image] | [image] |

Any idea or suggestion is welcome...

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the correct forum to ask, I think it's more something for stackoverflow. Nevertheless, it depends what is "the best green" you could have. Is it in RGB (0, 255, 0)? If so, if you don't have any shadow, you could take the average color of all relevant pixels (e.g. the bottom half of the picture). After converting to HSV-format, you could look at the percentage of the V-value or the percentage how much green is in there (e.g. (0, 127, 0) would give 50%)

Comment: Well, I don't have problem to code the algorithm once I know the formula. I was just hoping there are some non-trivial metrics of colored images, beyond regular things, like mean and median, which could help me.